# Open Instagram in IOS 9 with UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, instagram, ios9

Hi this is my code to open Instagram App directly with an image. As stated in Apple document relative to UIDocumentInteractionController and in Instagram hook page this snippet of code should open instagram directly with the image, but in all testing conditions it open the action sheet with all the app compatible with the extension saved.

I've also whitelisted instagram  in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

How can i achive this result? It's a bug or a new security feature of IOS 9?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram:/"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.ig"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturedImage) writeToFile:getImagePath atomically:YES];
NSURL *imageFileURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:getImagePath];
NSLog(@"imag %@",imageFileURL);

self.dic.delegate = self;
self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:imageFileURL usingDelegate:self];
[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];

} else  //prompt for app missing


- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL
                                           usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate { 
UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
return interactionController;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you save the image as `.igo` the only apps i see in the actionsheet are "Instagram" "Notes" and "other.

edit: I have't found a way to open Instagram directly with an image it only seems possible to open it directly with

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

but you can't add an image with that

edit2: I forgot to add that for the .igo format you need to use `self.dic.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"`

Comment: Several related questions report the same issue, the only hope is that apple correct this behavior..